# Enable tab completion to find file in Julia outside working directory

Tags: julia

How can I enable tab completion in Julia with a function I wrote that loads a file outside of the working directory? Tab completion is super nice, but it only seems to work for files in my working directory. e.g. I store all of my files in a directory `foo` and I wrote a function to conveniently read these files.

```
const WHEREMUHFILES = "foo/"
function read_foo_file(filename::String)
    readlines(WHEREMUHFILES * filename)
end
```

However, when I try `read_foo_file("ba` and hit Tab, tab completion doesn't work, in that it doesn't search the directory `WHEREMUHFILES` for `bar.txt`. Is there a way to enable this?

In reality, I have many different types of files organized in different directories, and the `read_foo_file` populates complex data structures after reading in the files, so a simple work around such as "put your files in your working directory!" is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Not exactly what your asking for but (assuming `WHEREMUHFILES` is an absolute path) you can of course just `cd(WHEREMUHFILES)`, i.e. make it your working directory.

Comment: I'm assuming you're referring to the interpreter's autocompletion facilities. Unfortunately, if you had it your way, the situation would invariably lead to conflicts. A hacky workaround you could try is to create your own struct, taking in a directory or list of directories as an argument, which you then use to initialise a Dict field, using the filename strings as both keys and values. You can then use autocompletion on the Dict's _keys_, returning the same string as its value. If you'd like to see an example I can write one as an answer later.